# Data structure to hold a list of timestamped objects

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a list of timestamped objects and the only query I need to execute would be "find all objects with a timsetamp greater than x".
Which data structure would be best suited to optimize the above lookup? I am fine with larger insertion times, but would prefer not to go with a full EPL implementation if possible.

Comment: what is a timestamped object in your app? An object that contains a date field?

Comment: Interval tree is the first thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using an SQL database in your application somewhere, then create an index for the timestamp field and just make the query.

Otherwise if you don't have database, this looks like a job for either [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [ConcurrentSkipList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html). Both implements the [subMap(K, K)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20K%29), [headMap(K)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#headMap%28K%29), and [tailMap(K)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#tailMap%28K%29) method from [NavigableMap interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html). You can specify a custom ordering for any SortedMap (and its subinterfaces) by implementing [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in your keys or by specifying [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) when creating your collection. If you don't need to have key-value mapping, you can also simply use [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) and their implementations [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) or [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html).

Comment: The structure is in memory (no db). The implementations of NavigableMap (especially in google collections) looks promising. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Could you please mention the Comparable<T> interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:

```
//declare an ArrayList of Objects
ArrayList<MyTimestampedObject> list = loadObjects();

//new list to store Objects after condition check
ArrayList<MyTimestampedObject> newList = new ArrayList<MyTimestampedObject>();

//loop through the list
for(MyTimestampedObject tmp:list ){

  //check condition
  if(tmp.getDate()>x){
    //do something
    newList.add(tmp);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, this would be an O(N) solution. I'm looking for something more optimial if possible

Comment: I believe that implementing the comparable interface is much better

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sorted data structure that allows binary search (if you don't care about insertion time), and for a given a `X`, perform a search (which takes `O(logN)` time) to find the first object with `timestamp > X`, because the data structure is ordered, all the objects in the data structure after this object also have `timestamp > X`.

Note that if you want to **return** a list of object from this query, it can't be done better than `O(N)`- you will either copy or delete `O(N)` times, as the number of objects that can be retrieved in this query in the general case is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about a BST (binary search tree ? InOrder gives you exactly what you need , with O(logn).